# inheritance in rlang's env_get doesn't seem to see bindings in the grandparent environment

Tags: r, rlang, r-environment

In the following example, I try to get an element from a grandparent environment using `env_get`. The first bit works as expected.

```r
library(rlang)
e1 <- env(a = 'a')

# works as expected
f <- function() {
  env_get(
    env = caller_env(), 
    nm = 'a', 
    inherit = TRUE, 
    default = 'not found')
}
exec(f, .env = e1)
#> [1] "a"

# two levels deep of function calls doesn't work even though inherit = TRUE
g <- function() f()
exec(g, .env=e1)
#> [1] "not found"


# modifying the depth of caller_env in f does work
f <- function() {
  env_get(
    env = caller_env(2), # <------ changing this
    nm = 'a', 
    inherit = TRUE, 
    default = 'not found')
}
exec(g, .env=e1)
#> [1] "a"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I expected that the second bit, calling `exec` on `g` with `.env=e1` would work, as the call to `env_get` has `inherit=TRUE`. My understanding was that it would look in the `caller_env`, find nothing, and look in its parent to find `"a"`, but this did not work. Further confusing me on this is what when I explicitly instruct `env_get` to look 2 levels up, this does work.

Am I misunderstanding something about how this inheritance should work?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused over two concepts:

- Calling environment: where the function is called. This is the return value of `caller_env()`.
- Execution/Evaluation environment: where the object/function is evaluated. This is the return value of `current_env()`.

When you `exec` a function in an environment `e1`, the function would be called in `e1`, but its arguments and the procedures written in its body would be evaluated in an isolated environment, that is, `current_env()`. Usually, `current_env()` exists only temporarily and will be destroyed upon completion of the function evaluation. Another important thing is that the parent envionment of `current_env()` is not `caller_env()` but where the function is created. For instance,

```
e1 <- new.env()
h <- function() {
  print(c(
    h_evaluated_in = current_env(), 
    h_called_in = caller_env(), 
    parent_of_current = parent.env(current_env())
  ))
}
list(e1_is = e1); exec(h, .env = e1); exec(h, .env = e1)
```

Output (note that `h` is evaluated in a different enviornment each time)

```
$e1_is
<environment: 0x000002e731f5c1b8>

$h_evaluated_in
<environment: 0x000002e731f59cb0>

$h_called_in
<environment: 0x000002e731f5c1b8>

$parent_of_current
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

$h_evaluated_in
<environment: 0x000002e731f58180>

$h_called_in
<environment: 0x000002e731f5c1b8>

$parent_of_current
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Now we can go back to your examples.

- In the first case, `f` is called in `e1`. `f` is executed in some isolated environment (call it *temp*). In *temp*, `f` calls `env_get(...)`. The `caller_env()` of `f` is thus `e1`. `e1`'s parent environment is `global_env()`. `env_get(...)` stops in `e1` because it finds a binding `a` there.
- In the second case, `g` is called in `e1`. `g` is executed in some isolated environment (call it *temp*). In *temp*, `g` calls `f()`. The `caller_env()` of `f` is thus *temp*. *temp*'s parent environment is `global_env()`. `env_get(...)` cannot find binding `a` in either *temp* or `global_env()` and thus return `"not found"`.
- In the last case, `g` is called in `e1`. `g` is executed in some isolated environment (call it *temp*). In *temp*, `g` calls `f()`. The `caller_env()` of `f` is thus *temp*. The `caller_env(2)` of `f` is `e1` since `g` calls `f()` and `g` is called in `e1`. `e1`'s parent environment is `global_env()`. `env_get(...)` stops in `e1` because it finds a binding `a` there.

#### Futher reading

[Environments - Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)